# wildcard virtualhost for wordpress multisite

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, virtualhost, spoofing

I am using a wildcard virtualhost for my local dev environment as follows:

```
ServerAlias *.local
VirtualDocumentRoot "c:/dev/sites/%1/www"
```

this works as expected. I create a new site in the sites folder, and navigating to newsite.local loads the site. The problem is that I use a multisite Wordpress configuration. So navigating to subsite.newsite.local does not load. I assume this is because Apache will be looking for a folder structure:

```
c:/dev/sites/subsite.newsite/www
```

instead of pointing to the domain directory:

```
c:/dev/sites/newsite/www
```

My question is, how do I write the virtualhost directive, so that any subdomains point to the root domain ?

e.g.

```
site.local -> c:/dev/sites/site/www
subsite.site.local -> c:/dev/sites/site/www
subsite-two.site.local -> c:/dev/sites/site/www
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by looking into the documentation for mod_vhost_alias
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

By hashing from the end of the name:

```
ServerAlias *.local
VirtualDocumentRoot "c:/dev/sites/%-2/www"
```